# Browser based software solutions in offline mode

Tags: office365, sharepoint, offline-files, dynamics-crm

**Scenario:**

Internet connectivity has been lost due to a fault in the line or technical issues which the ISP is experiencing.

*And/Or*

The servers hosting the software browser based solutions have developed a fault, so they are down.  For example, the servers down may be any or all of the sql, dns, sharepoint servers etc.

**Software being used:**

Browser based software Microsoft SharePoint/Dynamics + Office 365.

**Client side hardware being used:**

Laptops

**Question:**

Can users continue to work on the laptops with such browser based software solutions (in some form of offline mode), where there work is automatically stored locally and then automatically sync'ed to the servers as soon as internet connectivity and/or server faults are corrected?

Comment: This is a very broad question that is asking about an entire enterprise-class solution. Frankly, the question isn't "can it..." but "what is necessary to do..." Most clouds I'm familiar with already have an offline mode, so your best bet is to check out the documentation for Office365 for their capabilities in this matter.

Comment: I'm starting to see your goal given the recent questions you've been asking. You may want to consider a completely different kind of solution: having a second location that people can go to in the case of an event. The second location would basically provide internet and power and it is a requirement that you work entirely in the cloud, but with office365 that is not an issue.

Comment: @LPChip, that's an interesting idea!